# Is there a command for inserting a line of characters in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublimetext

I tend to use lines of hashes and dashes for formatting and breaking up code files (e.g., CSS files):

```
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Layout Styles
 * -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

In `vim` I would use the command `80a-<ESC>` which would [insert 80 `-` characters from the location after the cursor](http://aijazansari.com/2011/11/28/how-to-insert-a-line-of-dashes-in-vim/).

I've poked around in the Sublime documentation, but haven't come across a good way of replicating the above `vim` command in `subl`. Vintage mode does not include support for this command sequence.

Is there a corresponding command that does something similar in Sublime or would a static snippet be the simplest solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think there is any repeat character possibility. To do this with any character I think would require a plugin, but the basic functionality of inserting a big comment block can easily be achieved with a snippet:

Go to `New Snippet` through the menus and add this code:

```
<snippet>
    <content>
        <![CDATA[
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------
 * $0
 * -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
        ]]>
    </content>
<tabTrigger>comment</tabTrigger>
</snippet>
```

then save the snippet in your `Packages\User` folder, as `something.sublime-snippet`. Should work straight away, you just have to type `comment` (or whatever you change it to..) then hit `tab`, then actually write your comment title.

Comment: That's sort of what I thought based on the docs. Thanks for confirming!